# How can I make a rounded image with a label in it?

Tags: jquery, css

How can I make like this image which has a label within it.

thanks.

[image]

I have tried this css for making the image rounded, but I am not able to make a label like this provided image.

```
.img-circle {
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 25%;
    height: 25%;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

<img src=".." class="img-circle" />
```

Comment: Please provide a [**MVCE**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). You need to show at least the code you've tried so far.

Comment: OK thanks, I've added my code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use one element with `img` inside and add `:after` pseudo element, or you can use image as [`background`](https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/1125/)

```css
.el {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 2px solid red;
}
.el:after {
  content: '1';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  background: red;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 30px;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="el">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100">
</div>
```

Comment: You could improve this by using an attribute such as data-label and then set the content using the **attr() css function**, this will let the user define the text in the markup. [**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/rickyruizm/dec6cdrc/)

Comment: @Ricardo Ruiz That is nice, but i am not sure about browser support so i will leave the answer as it is.

Comment: The support is really bad if it's not defined in the content property, but in content it should be fine. [Used in content support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-gencontent) vs [Not used in content support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css3-attr)

Comment: @NenadVracar that's fabulous, thanks so much, worked like magic.

Comment: @RicardoRuiz it's really a great improvement, that's helped me too thank you

Comment: You can thank Nenad by marking this as the correct answer `: )`

Answer (score 1):

You can create wrapper that will contain image and label, like here:
https://jsfiddle.net/9e7h2LLf/

```
.wrapper{
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 2px solid red;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
}

img {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}

.label {
  background-color: red;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

<div class="wrapper">
  <img src="https://image.freepik.com/free-vector/bathroom-mosaic-pattern_23-2147497370.jpg">
  <span class="label">1</span>
</div>
```

Or create a round wrapper and use image as background, like here:
https://jsfiddle.net/3jmfcudo/

```
.wrapper{
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 2px solid red;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-image: url("https://image.freepik.com/free-vector/bathroom-mosaic-pattern_23-2147497370.jpg");
  background-size: contain;
  position: absolute;
}

.label {
  background-color: red;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

<div class="wrapper">
<span class="label">1</span>
</div>
```